# How do you pronounce the name "Augustin-Louis Cauchy"?

Tags: prononciation

It's the name of [a French mathematician.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin_Louis_Cauchy)

I would like to get an approximate pronunciation. (e.g. je t'aime~zh tam, or zhe tehm).

Comment: What part of the name did you find hard to pronounce ? (out of sheer curiosity)

Comment: All of it actually. I heard the "in" in many French names become like "aN". Some say it as "kow shee", with ow as in low, others say it "koo shee". I'd probably say Louis as "loo wee".

Comment: [forvo](http://forvo.com/search/Augustin-Louis%20Cauchy/)

Comment: @BorisTreukhov make it an answer, please :)

Comment: I think the forvo link clarifies it up. I believe the voice there was that of an actual person instead of a machine like in GoogleTrans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Au
```

As in ***Au***​stralia.

```
gus
```

With the famous non-English ü, close front rounded vowel [y].

```
tin
```

As French ***matin***​, or *teint*.

```
Louis
```

As in Saint-***Loui***​s (Missouri), without pronouncing the final *s*.

```
Cau
```

As in ***co***-op.

```
chy
```

As the english word *she*.

Comment: And I'd pronounce the o of Augustin and of Cauchy in the same way [o], while I think that co-op is more open. (As for [œ̃] and [ɛ̃] some accents don't make a difference between [o] and [ɔ])

Comment: I agree, they're the same [o]. And I was really talking about the "co" part of co-op.

Comment: In this case, you pronounce _in_ from _tin_ exactly like you pronounce the number _1_. In general, I agree that it may differ, but here it's absolutely the same sound.

Comment: It's `ɛ̃` like in *lin* or *teint*, not `œ̃` like *un* (the number *1*). Downvoted for as long as this is not corrected.

Comment: Fine, even though I can't hear the difference. I will correct it, but please suggest another word, more ordinary than _lin_. We are trying to help someone who is not fluent in french, and this word is not common enough.

Comment: Just “matin”, is it common enough? Usually the writing “in” is pronounced `ɛ̃` (nasalized `ɛ` like in *chèvre*) while “un” is pronounced `œ̃` (nasalized `œ` like in *heure*).

Comment: Perfect. I updated the post.

Comment: I think saying "tin" as in matin won't help-- I don't think this person knows basic French pronunciation.

Comment: Well, I think it's used enough to have an idea of the pronunciation... But you can suggest another word if you want.

Answer (score 7):

For anglophones who need to pronounce foreign names while speaking English, I highly recommend the following website (written by a topologist colleague back when he was a radio announcer for a classical music station):
http://www.pronunciationguide.info/

I emphasize "while speaking English" because, if you are speaking English, you need to approximate the real pronunciation of the name with English phonemes.  If you pronounce "Louis-Augustin Cauchy" absolutely correctly in English, a fair number of English speakers will only hear the foreignness of the sounds, and not the actual sounds themselves.  (More extreme examples of this difficulty come from Chinese or Slavic names.)

Similarly, if you are speaking French, you will need to approximate English names with French phonemes.  There is a possible exception if you are in an area like Montreal where a lot of franglais is spoken, but a fair number of bilingual French (or bilingual Americans) are at least occasionally confused by mixing phonemes from the two languages they speak in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend, or better say it's text-to-speech companion : http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=Augustin-Louis%20Cauchy

Comment: Thanks. I never thought Google translate's feature would be accurate enough. au gis tanN Lwi kooshi.

Comment: @FrenchNoob What in the world is this phonetic syntax ? I never saw that.

Comment: That's how I approximate Google translate's reading. au as in august. My Idiot's Guide to French would probably write lwee for Louis but I suppose the ee is shorter, so I write lwi. Works for me though.

Comment: @FrenchNoob I find strange that you make a difference between au of Augustin and au of Chauchy. I do not, not even one of length.

Comment: @Un francophone So Google translate's pronunciation isn't accurate after all. I'm positive it pronounces the two au's differently.

Comment: I must admit I, too, can't make a difference, neither pronoucing myself, nor in google's tts.

Answer (score -1):

Like Koshi. Koshi is a Malayalee name. Cauchy is pronounced Ko shi /
KO SHE.

Comment: The question has already been answered and this answer might not be helpful if OP doesn't speak French. Only someone with a good background of French pronunciation can make the link between "Koshi" and "Cauchy". By the way, avoid using things like "get it?" on Stack Exchange, it is not very appropriate.